# Requiring Google Mobile Service token

Tags: android, penetration-test, google, access-token

I'm pentesting an android application written in Cordova and while inspecting the network traffic I found some interesting endpoint that I would like to test.
However, this endpoint need a tokenID (ex. `eyJ[...].eyJ[...]`) and I don't know why, even after doing **SSL unpinning** (with more than one Frida script), I'm unable to intercept the request that is used to generate the token.

After some static analysis, I realized that the token is being requested by `com.android.gms` (Google Mobile Service).

I managed to find the `gcm_defaultSenderId`, `google_api_key` and `google_app_id`. However, since the apk is obfuscated, I didn't manage to discover how to craft the request.

Do any of you know if there is a way to craft **gms** tokens using a script?

Comment: The app must be using Google's Firebase API. You have to intercept communication of  Google Play Services with Google as well.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @defalt. This must be it, because the application does use FIrebase. Any guess on how to SSL unpin Google Play Services with frida?

Comment: Root the device and use SSLUnpinning 2.0 xposed framework module.